# Detecting mouse clicks on a gameobject

Tags: unity-game-engine

Here is my code that attached with the game object that I want to click

```
void Update () {

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) 
    {                    
            Application.LoadLevel("option");

}
```

And it seems like I can click anywhere on screen for make "Application.LoadLevel("option");" run.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: That is because you are only checking if the mouse button was clicked not where it was clicked.

Comment: You could use a raycast to check what was under the mouse click. instructions here http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/28064/get-mouse-position-on-object.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @Qwertie said, where are you clicking is important. If your GameObject has collider attached, then you can use `OnMouseDown()`. This will be called whenever you click on the gameobject having collider and this script as a component.

```
void OnMouseDown()
{

     Application.LoadLevel("option");

}
```

Comment: but adding collider allows the object to collide with other game objects as well. Be careful when using

Comment: You can create an extra layer for them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private Vector3 currentMouseDown;
void OnMouseOver ()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
        currentMouseDown = Input.mousePosition;
        Debug.Log ("down");

    }
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp (0) && currentMouseDown != null) {
        Debug.Log ("Up");
        if (currentMouseDown == Input.mousePosition) {
            Debug.Log ("get");
        }
    }
}
```

This code will solve drag conflict problem.